# How do I upload code coverage data from Heroku-CI to Code Climate?

Tags: heroku, code-climate

I'm trying to upload code coverage data from Heroku-CI to Code Climate and I'm running into a problem. The Code Climate uploader seems to expect the project to be a git repository and somehow Heroku-CI removed the `.git` folder.

When it runs, I get this error:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
Error: exit status 128
```

Any ideas what's the correct solution here? Why is the .git folder gone? Can Code Climate work regardless somehow?

The full debug output is:

```
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="about to run format-coverage" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="searching for a formatter to use" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking clover formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking search path build/logs/clover.xml for clover formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking search path clover.xml for clover formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking cobertura formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking search path cobertura.xml for cobertura formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking coverage.py formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking search path coverage.xml for coverage.py formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking gcov formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking search path ./ for GCov formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking gocov formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking search path c.out for gocov formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking jacoco formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking search path jacoco.xml for jacoco formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking lcov-json formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking excoveralls formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking search path cover/excoveralls.json for excoveralls formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking lcov formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking search path coverage/lcov.info for lcov formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking simplecov formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking search path coverage/coverage.json for simplecov formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="checking search path coverage/.resultset.json for simplecov formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:51Z" level=debug msg="found file coverage/.resultset.json for simplecov formatter" 
time="2021-03-09T12:22:52Z" level=debug msg="couldn't load committed at from ENV, trying git..." 
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
Error: exit status 128
Usage:
  cc-test-reporter after-build [flags]
Flags:
  -s, --batch-size int               batch size for source files (default 500)
  -e, --coverage-endpoint string     endpoint to upload coverage information to (default "https://api.codeclimate.com/v1/test_reports")
  -t, --coverage-input-type string   type of input source to use [clover, cobertura, coverage.py, excoveralls, gcov, gocov, jacoco, lcov, lcov-json, simplecov, xccov]
      --exit-code int                exit code of the test run
  -r, --id string                    reporter identifier
      --insecure                     send coverage insecurely (without HTTPS)
  -p, --prefix string                the root directory where the coverage analysis was performed (default "/app")
Global Flags:
  -d, --debug   run in debug mode
-----> test command `bundle exec rake spec && ls -la && ./cc-test-reporter after-build --exit-code $? --debug` failed with exit status 255
```

and just before that I made my CI run `ls -la` and indeed, there's no `.git` folder:

```
total 13448
drwx------  24 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 root   root     4096 Feb 24 07:43 ..
drwx------  11 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:19 app
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno     1092 Mar  9 12:19 app.json
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno     1661 Mar  9 12:19 babel.config.js
drwx------   2 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:19 bin
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno        9 Mar  9 12:19 .browserslistrc
drwx------   2 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:19 .bundle
drwx------   3 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:21 .cache
-rwx------   1 u26906 dyno 13206167 Mar  9 12:20 cc-test-reporter
drwx------   6 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:19 config
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno      160 Mar  9 12:19 config.ru
drwx------   3 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:22 coverage
drwx------   3 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:19 db
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno       47 Mar  9 12:19 .env.example
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno     1843 Mar  9 12:19 Gemfile
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno     9282 Mar  9 12:19 Gemfile.lock
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno      327 Mar  9 12:19 .gitattributes
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno      785 Mar  9 12:19 .gitignore
drwx------   5 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:20 .heroku
drwx------   5 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:19 .idea
drwx------   4 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:19 lib
drwx------   2 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:20 log
drwx------ 812 u26906 dyno    36864 Mar  9 12:21 nod_modules
drwx------   3 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:21 .npm
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno      564 Mar  9 12:19 package.json
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno      303 Mar  9 12:19 postcss.config.js
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno        1 Mar  9 12:19 Procfile
drwx------   2 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:20 .profile.d
drwx------   4 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:22 public
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno      258 Mar  9 12:19 Rakefile
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno       67 Mar  9 12:19 README.md
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno       22 Mar  9 12:19 .rspec
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno        6 Mar  9 12:19 .ruby-version
drwx------  11 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:19 spec
drwx------   3 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:19 .sprettur
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno      182 Mar  9 12:19 .standard.yml
drwx------   2 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:19 storage
drwx------   4 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:22 tmp
drwx------   6 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:19 vendor
drwx------   2 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:19 .vscode
drwx------   3 u26906 dyno     4096 Mar  9 12:20 .yarn
-rw-------   1 u26906 dyno   349818 Mar  9 12:19 yarn.lock
```